# Tikhonov space and Stone-Čech compactification

Tags: general-topology

> If $X$ is a Tikhonov space for which $F\subseteq X$ closed and $x\notin F$, then $x\notin\operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(F)$.

As $X$ is a Tikhonov space for which $F\subseteq X$ closed and $x\notin F$, there exists a continuous function $f\colon X\to[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f[A]\subseteq\{1\}$. Since $f$ is continuous and $[0,1]$ is compact Hausdorff, there exists a continuous function $\beta f\colon \beta X\to[0,1]$ for which $\beta f\vert_{X} = f$.

Where can I go from here?

Comment: In full strictness mode we'd need to prove that $e(x) \notin \operatorname{cl}_{\beta X} e[F]$ but, what's an embedding between friends, eh? the proof would be essentially the same.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: I see how these problems work now, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your question considers $X$ to be a subspace of $\beta X$. (this ignores the embedding which we would have in general) I will continue with that idea: indeed $f: X \to [0,1]$ exists so that $f(x)=0$ and $f[A]=\{1\}$. We have $\beta f: \beta X \to [0,1]$ then as a "real" extension from the subspace $X$ to $\beta X$.

> Recall that for a continuous function $g: A \to B$ we have that $g[\overline{C}] \subseteq \overline{g[C]}$ for all $C \subseteq X$.

It follows that $$\beta f[\operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(F)] \subseteq \operatorname{cl}_{[0,1]} \beta f[F]$$

and as the right hand set just equals $\operatorname{cl}_{[0,1]}(f[F]) = \{1\}$ as $\beta f =f$ on $X$ and $\{1\}$ is closed in $[0,1]$, and as $\beta f(x)=f(x)=0$, it's clear that $x \notin \operatorname{cl}_{\beta X}(F)$.

Comment: Thank you, again! The whole *ignoring the embedding* was confusing me, but I see now.

Comment: @D.Math You *can* sort of ignore the embedding in practice, but you have to be aware that you're doing it. It gets more important when you want to consider different inequivalent compactifications. In practive I always think of $\beta X$ as sitting around $X$ (like a large blob).

Comment: That's a good way of thinking about it. I'm curious, though, say $\tilde{X}$ is the one point compactification of $X$, then is it true $X\subseteq\tilde{X}$?

Comment: @D.Math Not strictly: **a** one-point compactification of $X$ is a compcatification pair $(e,Y)$ for $X$ with $Y\setminus e[X]$ is a singleton. There are many such compactifications. One concrete construction is  the Alexandroff extension $aX$ of $X$, which obeys $X \subseteq aX$ (hence *extension*).  But there is a theorem probably shown in your text, that *all* one-point compactifications are equivalent (!) (in particular, the spaces are homeomorphic), and people choose to work with $aX$ among those.

Comment: Hmm, well the way I see it defined is given a Hausdorff, locally compact, non-compact space $X$ and $p\notin X$ and define $\tilde{X}:=X\cup\{p\}$. Then defined a local base on $\tilde{X}$ for which it is compact.

Comment: @D.Math that's $aX$ indeed. From the definition I gave it's already clear that $e[X]$ is open in $Y$ so $e[X]$ (hence $X$) must be locally compact for such a compif. to exist. Etc. But you've only learnt the concrete model, not the general one?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by "concrete model" and the "general one", but the way compactification(s) was taught to me, in class, was first compactification, then one-point compactification (Alexandroff), and then the Stone-Čech compactification.

Comment: @D.Math Too bad. A more abstract treatment is more appropriate here, I think. There is a very rich theory of compactifications, and this way, you only see one example for Tychonoff spaces ($\beta X$, with a hard general theory to really grasp) and for some spaces a simple one ($aX$). It oversimplifies too much to my taste.

Comment: I agree, too bad. The course is being taught by a *dynamist*, so perhaps such a topic is of no interest to them.